# Mysql ABS function unexplained bug in code

Tags: mysql

Consider the following query:

```
SELECT p . * 
FROM multiple_picks p
WHERE p.event_id =  '3303'
AND p.pick =  'Highlanders'
AND ABS( p.score -  '8' ) = ( 
SELECT MIN( ABS( p2.score -1 ) ) 
FROM multiple_picks p2
WHERE p2.pick = p.pick
AND p2.event_id = p.event_id )
```

The query above should return the member(s) who **selected the CORRECT TEAM AND the MEMBER(S) who was CLOSEST to Selecting the score. If it is a tie - more than one member should be returned!**

When I run the above query on the following table, named multiple_picks:

[image]

I get the following result back:

[image]

**MY PROBLEM**

The result returned is incorrect as you can clearly see!

Since the winning team was the Highlanders with a score by 8 (as seen in the query)

The correct result which should have been returned is row2 (the member who picked the Highlanders by 10!)

Any advice as to why I am getting this incorrect result, or what I am doing wrong will be greatly appreciated! Been stuck on this for days now!

[SQL FIDDLE](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d11cf/4)

Comment: Your logic seems flawed. If you need the person who was the closest to selecting 8 then you need the member who's `p.score - 8` is the closest to 0 not the one which is the closest to the minimum - 1.

Comment: @apokryfos thank you so that is an area to inspect for me then, do you perhaps have any suggestion to what `p.score - 8` should be changed to?

Comment: `p.score - 8` is fine, the inner min should be something like `MIN( ABS( p2.score - 8))` that way you're comparing like with like.

Comment: @apokryfos would you mind having a look at mysql fiddle link posted below post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that p.score - (const) is compared to p2.score - 1 which is not consistent.

Here's the idea (If I understood the question correctly).

Assume you have variables (or something like that):

> T = 'Highlanders'
>
> S = 8

This means you need to find the entry which has `p.pick=T` and for which the p.score is the closest to S.

Here's what you do (replaced the hardcoded values with the variables above to not distract from the essence of the question) :

```
SELECT p . * 
FROM multiple_picks p
WHERE p.event_id =  '3303'
AND p.pick =  T
AND ABS(p.score - S) = ( 
    SELECT MIN(ABS(p2.score - S)) 
    FROM multiple_picks p2
    WHERE p2.pick = p.pick
    AND p2.event_id = p.event_id 
)
```

[Updated SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d11cf/2)

Comment: BIngo! You understood correct obviously the hardcoded values will get replaced with php variables....but running your code I get the correct result. Thank you so much!!